# Cannot add Microsoft.Ink

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-ink

I have a c# codebehind to a web app I'm trying to add "using Microsoft.Ink" to, but it is not a valid namespace. Is there something I need to install before I do this? The documentation from Microsoft seems all over the place and there are no instructions on how to include this in the file.
I checked in the modify menu for Visual Studio to see if I could add anything for tablet support and there is nothing.

How do I add "using Microsoft.Ink"?

Comment: I am not familiar with Microsoft Ink, but just looking through some of the classes in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.ink.aspx) I see that many of them exist in the `Microsoft.Ink` assembly.  Have you added a reference to this assembly to your project?

Comment: I searched for the assembly and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you seen [Managed Library and Controls (Tablet PC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms704070.aspx)?  I'm on 64-bit Windows 10 Pro with Visual Studio 2015 and I have `Microsoft.Ink.dll` in both `%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared\Ink` and `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Ink`.

Comment: Wow that worked. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You know that your users won't see this in their browser, right? Anything with Microsoft.Ink likely only works in test because your web server and your web browser are on the same machine.

Comment: No possibility of sending JSON coordinates from the browser to the server and Ink processing it?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft.Ink comes with the Table PC SDK. The dll would be found in 
`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Tablet PC\versionNo\`
though it is quite an old library, and I think it it intended for WinForms, not Web.

If you wanted to move away from ASP.NET, alternatives you might want to look into are [System.Windows.Ink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ink(v=vs.110).aspx) for WPF or the [InkCanvas control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas) on UWP.

Comment: But if I went for WPF or UWP I wouldn't be using a web application that's accessible through a browser right?

Answer (score 1):

According to the article [Managed Library and Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms704070.aspx) under the [Windows Tablet PC documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms704849.aspx), the managed library assemblies are installed to the following directories:

- `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Ink\`
- `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin\`

I am using 64-bit Windows 10 Pro with Visual Studio 2015 and I have a `Microsoft.Ink.dll` file in both `%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Shared\Ink\` and `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Ink\`.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has just:

```
Csharp
Internal
Runtime
SqlServer
VisualBasic
Win32
```

there is no lnk option.
if you had a modified dll then you can add it to add reference if you want.

Comment: So then how would I add handwriting support?